# How can I use raw_input in the text editor Atom.io using the script Python 2.7.3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-editor, atom-editor

I am fairly new to editing scripts and have tried running the code in atom.io:

raw_input("hello what is your name?")

The terminal does not give me and output and shows an hourglass which never changes.

Am I missing something here?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

[Currently Atom Script does not support STDIN.](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/issues/197)